# Angular CLI, Teamcity and NPM, support multiple versions

Tags: angular, npm, teamcity, angular-cli

We have multiple projects being built by teamcity invoking ng build, however we've now got a requirement to upgrade one of the projects to a later version of angular and angular cli.

The problem we have is now Teamcity needs to be able to work with different versions of angular and angular cli, angular isn't a problem as it's installed locally to the project but angular cli is installed globally.

How can we keep working on other projects that we simply don't have the time to upgrade at this moment? Is there a way around having angular cli installed globally?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple and I've no idea why I even needed to ask the question. Angular/AngularCLI does not need to be installed globally so will not affect other projects.

With each build we

1. Checkout from Source Control
2. Run `npm install`
3. Run `ng build`

Because angular cli/angular is installed locally the above works just fine.

Comment: Did you encounter any issues when a NodeJS upgrade was required? Eg one of your builds needed a newer version of node in order to support a newer CLI?

Comment: I no longer work on this project, sorry.